# Adding together combinations to reach a target number

Tags: c#, wpf

```
     int bag = int.Parse(txtBag.Text);
        int item1 = int.Parse(txtItem1.Text);
        int item2 = int.Parse(txtItem2.Text);
        int item3 = int.Parse(txtItem3.Text);
        if (item1 <= bag)
        {
            item4 = item1;
            txtGenerate.Text = "item1";
            txtResult.Text = item4.ToString();
        }
        if(Solution(item1, item2))
        {
            txtGenerate.Text = "item1 + item2";
        }
        if(Solution(item2, item3))
        {
            txtGenerate.Text = "item2 + item3";
        }
        if(Solution(item1, item3))
        {
           txtGenerate.Text = "item1 + item3";
        }

    }
        public bool Solution(int item, int itemm)
        {
            int bag = int.Parse(txtBag.Text);
            if (item + itemm > item4 & item + itemm <= bag)
            {
                item4 = item + itemm;
                txtResult.Text = item4.ToString();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public bool Solution1(int item, int itemm, int itemmm)
        {
            int bag = int.Parse(txtBag.Text);
            if (item + itemm + itemmm > item4 & item + itemm + itemmm <= bag)
            {
                item4 = item + itemm + itemmm;
                txtResult.Text = item4.ToString();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I have this code, but I need it so that I can input any amount of numbers into a list then give it a target and it will find the closest combination to get to that number...

e.g. If the bag = 50 and item1 = 46, item2 = 25 & item3 = 24 item2 + item3 would be the solution because it gives you 49...

And it is in WPF

Comment: what's the problem you are facing with your current code? and can the closest combination higher than the target? how about different combination give you the same closest value?

Comment: @Bolu It will only let me use a max of 3 numbers and everytime I add a new number I need to do the If(Solution(item, itemm) everytime... and No it needs to either be equal to or less than

Comment: This is not a question specific to WPF or Visual Studio. The question is "given a list of numbers and a target, how to find out the two numbers from the list whose combination is closest to the target."

Comment: @kennyzx My mistake, But I dont just want the two numbers I want it with any amount, whichever gets the closest but is still less than the bag

Comment: You'll have to learn about arrays in .NET. Start with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx.

Comment: This is called the [0/1 knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) (in your case with values equal to weights).